# Waf: target is directory

Tags: python, waf

My wscript file is simple:

```py
def configure(ctx):
    pass

def build(bld):
    bld(rule='mkdir aaa', target='aaa')
    bld(rule='touch bbb', source='aaa', target='bbb')
```

And first run of `waf configure` and `waf build` passes OK. But the second `waf build` fails with an error:

```
source not found: 'aaa' in bld(source='aaa', target=['bbb'], meths=['process_rule', 'process_source'], features=[], path=/home/rnd/prj/prj2/prj-web, idx=2, tg_idx_count=2, rule='touch bbb', posted=True, _name='bbb') in /home/rnd/prj/prj2/prj-web
```

But if to change the "mkdir" to "touch" - everything works as expected. How to use a directory as a target? (PS. It would be interesting is it possible to use it as a source as well), because it's easy in a plain Makefile, so I had feeling that Waf can handle directories too.

Comment: Is it possible the issue is with `mkdir` itself which errors if the directory already exists? If you can use `mkdir -p` it does not error in that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the waf model don't manage directories with the `source` and `target` keywords. You can handle directories with specific keyword of your own, like `source_dir` and `target_dir`. Like :

```py
def my_rule(task):
    tg = task.generator
    target_dir = tg.path.get_bld().make_node(target_dir)
    target_dir.mkdir()
bld(rule=my_rule, target=dir = "bbb")
```